# Iterate variables from two tables sqlite python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, iteration

I have two tables in sqlite3 database with coordinates for different objects. Structured like id-longtitude-latitude. Let's name them `object1_coor` and `object2_coor`.

I just need to find distance between every object in `object1_coor` table and `object2_coor` table.

How can I do this in Python 3? As of now I've read a lot, but didn't find a solution for such iteration.

I'll use for distance algorithm below:

```
obj1_lat = radians(float(obj1_lat)))
obj1_lon = radians(float(obj1_lon)))
obj2_lat = radians(float(obj2_lat)))
obj2_lon = radians(float(obj2_lon)))

dist = 6371.01 * acos(sin(obj1_lat)*sin(obj2_lat) + cos(obj1_lat)*cos(obj2_lat)*cos(obj1_lon - obj2_lon))
print("The distance is " % dist)
```

Comment: The same way you would if your coordinates are in two lists: you create all unique combinations of the lists and produce the distances for each combination.

Comment: But I want in process of iteration check if distance ok for me, and if yes to put this in another table. Your point sounds good, but could you please help with code, I can’t understand how to read and iterate in parallel two tables. Diffucltiea in sql request and cursor

Comment: You don't iterate over the two tables; you'd iterate over a single select query. You could make a cross join between the two tables and take only distinct results; that should give you all possible combinations.

Comment: If you need to put the results into a separate table, then you'd most likely want a native function to calculate the distances, so you can just fill a table with the distance function output. You can do it in Python too, but it's a bit of a round trip.

Comment: Thanks I’ve got your point, will try snd share results

Comment: Use that formula in a SQL query, where you use `t1.longitude`, `t1.latitude`, `t2.longitude`, and `t2.latitude` after joining the two tables.

Comment: If you really want to do it on the Python side (which you really probably _don't_ want to do…), you need to read at least one rowset into a list (with `list(cursor)` or `cursor.fetch_all()` or whatever you prefer), and then you can use a nested loop or `itertools.product`, the same way you would for any list vs. any iterable. The fact that those iterables are rowsets doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the answer is below, tested different variants. For me was important to find all stores close each to other in area of 500m.Number of iterations 192 million, time to execute 246 seconds.

```
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM A_Coor CROSS JOIN B_Coor')
data = cur.fetchall() # read all databse

for coo in data:
    obj1_lat = radians(float(coo[1]))
    obj1_lon = radians(float(coo[2]))
    obj2_lat = radians(float(coo[5]))
    obj2_lon = radians(float(coo[6]))
    try:
        dist = 6371.01 * acos(sin(obj1_lat)*sin(obj2_lat) + cos(obj1_lat)*cos(obj2_lat)*cos(obj1_lon - obj2_lon))
        if dist < 0.5:
            print(" The distance is %.2fkm." % dist)
            near_pos = (coo[0], coo[1], coo[2], coo[3], coo[4], coo[5], coo[6], dist)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO fivehundred_stores (pos_cli, lat_mag, lon_mag, fake_id, pka_id, lat_pka, lon_pka, distance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", near_pos)
            near_pos = []
            con.commit()
    except:
        error_comb = []
        error_comb =(coo[0], coo[4])
        print (error_comb)
        error_comb = []
        pass
```

Comment: a bare except? also why not separate you read/write and distance calculation functions. looks a bit messy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, but I can’t fully understand you, it’s my second program on python, and if you can show me how to rework it in more smooth way, it would be great.

Comment: Please see in my answer

Comment: Ahh ok got you point. It’s better to define functions first, and the use them through the programm

Comment: one addition to splitting the script to functions is paying attention to levels of abstraction - eg data import and export is support task, you shoudl be able to change your data source and where you are exportign the result to without any harm to you core logic of data transformation, I think it's important to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Sergey, here is a sceleton for more structured code. General advice is to try separating your code into small, relatively independent, testable blocks. With this approch you are more likely to end with [maintainable programs](https://gist.github.com/sloria/7001839) and not some [spagretti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

```
def get_coordinates_cross_join():
    """Return a list of coordiantes"""
    # this may have namedtuples as a result
    pass    

def distance(a, b):
    """Calculate distance between points *a* and *b*."""
    pass

def insert(a, b):
    #insert a and b into database
    pass

# this can be main()    
for a, b in get_coordinates_cross_join():
    if distance(a, b) < 0.5:
        insert(a, b)
```

Comment: @Sergey Umnyakhin: care to [pick an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?